# Explain this Java Swing NetBeans autogenerated code

Tags: swing, netbeans

Can someone please tell me what does this auto-generated code mean.
Its from Netbeans IDE's GUI Builder.
I really need a website which can explain the auto-generated code of Netbeans.

```
    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(189, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel8)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(txt_name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(152, 152, 152))
    );
```

Comment: The Netbeans GUI builder just uses a GroupLayout for its UI. The [Layout manager tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) contains a section about it. Not sure what else you need

Comment: The best way to understand the releavant parts of this is to learn Swing. The [Java Tutorials Swing thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) gets recommended a lot but there might be other resources.

Comment: You should learn Swing first using the tutorials.  Only after your first 3,000 GUI's or so should you consider using a GUI builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much all explained by reading the JavaDocs on [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html).

Maybe you're confused by the fluent style?

Netbeans has done a pretty good job of visually arranging it, though.  Think of each indentation layer as adding another constraint.  It's horizontal, parallel (meaning they're aligned), and sequential (in a specific order).  Going left-to-right, we lay out

- A [gap between the edge of the edge of the layout and the first component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.SequentialGroup.html#addContainerGap%28int,%20int%29), ideally 189 pixels, but it can be bigger.
- A [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)
- A [gap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.SequentialGroup.html#addGap%28int,%20int,%20int%29) of exactly 18 pixels
- `txt_name` (whatever Component that is), preferably 212 pixels wide.
- A gap of exactly 152 pixels

Spend some time reading the JavaDocs and experimenting with small changes to the code and you'll get the hang of it.

**Or** you can decide to just blindly trust NetBeans and not learn how to work with layouts.  As long as you never need anything but a basic interface, that's a viable alternative.